# Oracle 10g claiming that a package body has errors when it does not

Tags: java, oracle, spring, plsql

I have a few packages on my oracle instance.  When I recreate my database from scratch, I get zero invalid objects, and no warnings from liquibase.

Then, when I call a package method, like so:

```
new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withCatalogName(packageName).withProcedureName(storedProcedureName).execute(parameterMap);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT.CREATE_SUMMARIES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [72000]; error code [4063]; ORA-04063: package body "ETPDEV.CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "ETPDEV.CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT"
ORA-06512: at line 1; 

nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04063: package body "ETPDEV.CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "ETPDEV.CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT"
ORA-06512: at line 1

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04063: package body "ETPDEV.CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "ETPDEV.CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT"
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Checking for invalid objects again turns up nothing. Compiling CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT again completes normally without errors.

I've tried a full schema recompile, but that did not work.

When I call it from SQLDeveloper, it works normally.

Comment: Are you running it using the same account in Java and SQLDeveloper?

Comment: Yes. Both accounts are the same. To ensure that there was no difference, I logged in as system and ran `show errors package ETPDEV.CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT` as well.  No errors.

Comment: You say both accounts are the same but are they both logging in as exactly the same user? This looks like a classic permissions issue.

Comment: Yes, they're exactly the same.  The only difference is that in sqlplus and SQLDeveloper, the code works, but in a jdbc call, it does not.

Comment: The meaning of `catalog` is not well-defined in jdbc, can you try to remove the `withCatalogName` call and use the package name as a prefix of the procedure name?

Comment: Using just `withProcedureName` generates `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature for CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT.CREATE_SUMMARIES - package name should be specified separately using '.withCatalogName("CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT")'`

Comment: Aha! By shoehorning in some calls to user_error in the java side, I was able to narrow it down and solve the problem.  Unbeknownst to me, in a separate test case, another package was mocked/replaced and then set back.  A schema change in the CALENDAR_MANAGEMENT package then caused it to be invalid.  By fixing the dependencies, I was able to get it to work consistently.

Comment: @JBristow please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into this error in my integration checks, and I didn't think to check the validity of the package WHILE it was running.

Dropping a simple bit of code right before the call for the package:

```
select name || ' - ' || line || ' - ' || text from user_errors order by name, sequence;
```

I found that a different test was not cleaning up after itself, but this one was, so when I looked at the DB before and after, it looked fine.